# Getting a no access token error on the Spotify API using it flask

Tags: python, flask, spotify, spotipy

This is the error code  https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/top/tracks?time_range=short_term&limit=10&offset=0:

> None, reason: None

This is the code where the issue comes from:

```
@app.route('/top-songs')
def top_songs():
    token_info = get_token()
    if not token_info:
        return "Not work"

    print("Access Token:", token_info['access_token'])
    access_token = token_info['access_token']
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=access_token)
    try:
        top_tracks = sp.current_user_top_tracks(limit=10, offset=0, time_range='short_term')['items']
    except spotipy.SpotifyException as e:
        print("Spotify API Error:", e)

    # Extract relevant information from top_tracks
    # Example: track_names = [track['name'] for track in top_tracks['items']]

    return render_template('index.html')
```

I am trying to print the top songs from the Spotify API and display it on a HTML file. The error seems to be coming up at the line:

```
top_tracks = sp.current_user_top_tracks(limit=10, offset=0, time_range='short_term')['items']
```

because I don't get the error if that is removed. Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Please post exactly the error you are getting. Also are you renewing the `access_token`?

Comment: This is the exact error i am seeing "spotipy.exceptions.SpotifyException: http status: 403, code:-1 - https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/top/tracks?time_range=medium_term&limit=50&offset=0:
 None, reason: None
"

Yes, I am making sure the access token is renewed within my code. If I try to pull saved songs or saved podcasts then that works fine. but when I try to pull the top artists or top songs of the current user then I receive that error. I also definitely have the "user-top-read" scope in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an HTTP Status code [403 Forbidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) (The server understands the request but refuses to authorize it.).

If you check Spotify Web API documentation about [Authorization](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/concepts/authorization#which-oauth-flow-should-i-use) you'll see a table below that says if you are using *Client credentials* (access_token) then you don't have access to user resources, which in this case you are trying to access `spotipy.Spotify.current_user_top_tracks()` which is why the API is raising an exception with HTTP status code 403.

To access user resources then you are going to need to authenticate using [Authorization code](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/tutorials/code-flow) as described in [spotipy documentation](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.22.1/#authorization-code-flow). In this case you need the scope `user-top-read`:

```py
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth

# You also need CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET to create the Spotify client
sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(scope="user-top-read"))
top_tracks = sp.current_user_top_tracks()["items"]
print(top_tracks)
```

Comment: I have a function that creates the oAuth that returns SpotifyOauth with all the things it needs like client ID, client secret, scope, and redirect. i tried to just redefine it in the function I am using to return the user's top artist, but because of the redirect URL it was telling me i had already defined it. I tried `token_info = create_spotify_oauth().get_cached_token()
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token_info)` but then I got the error "Only valid bearer authentication supported, reason: None" Not sure where I am going wrong. I really hope someone can help.

Comment: @christianfasole well, you are creating A spotify client object with the parameter `auth=` which is used to pass just the access token. Like I explained, only with access token you won't be able to access user information. You could try what I did above which is create one with `auth_manager=` or read the documentation on [cache handling](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.22.1/#customized-token-caching) which does have a FlaskSession handler

Comment: with what you had above I got an error saying I didn't have the client ID or client secret so I tried putting both in the code but then it wanted the redirect but there is nowhere I can reroute it.

Comment: [SpotifyOAuth](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.22.1/#spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOAuth) can take `(client_id=None, client_secret=None, redirect_uri=None, ...)` the redirect URL just has to be any valid URL it doesn't matter which, you can use http://localhost but it *MUST* match what you have in your Spotify dashboard. Here is an example `sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(client_id="JD28DJ2DASA",client_secret="JN239DNAK2",redirect_uri="http://localhost",scope="user-top-read"))`

Comment: when I match it with the one in my Spotify dashboard I get this error "OSError: [Errno 48] Address already in use"

Comment: @christianfasole use a different redirect_uri, the address you're trying to use is probably taken by flask in the same project